# Dynamic left attr issue on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('div').css('left' ,$("id").scrollLeft());},
```

I tried this code to give a `div` a `left` attribute that will change depending on the `scrollLeft` function. It works perfectly on chrome but the content flicks on internet explorer whenever i drag the horizontal scroll.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Hi @codeval could you send a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/EzXub/263/              if you try this code in internet explorer 11 , you willl notice that the "#HEADER" its content flickers when drag the horizontal scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used and it worked in Chrome and IE 11

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                alert($("#test1").scrollLeft() + " px");
                $('#test2').css('left', $("#test1").scrollLeft());
            });

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                $('#test2').css({ 'left': 20 + $(this).scrollLeft() + 'px' });
            });
        }); 
    </script>
    <style>
        div {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:1000px;">
        <div id="test1">
            <div style="width:200px;">
                #test1 - Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <button>Click Here!</button>
        <div id="test2" style="position:absolute;">
            #test2
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: im trying to do something quite similar to this example jsfiddle.net/Starx/EzXub/263, and this works fine in chrome but not in ie11, as the #header content flickers when scrolling horizontally

Comment: Can you try my example in your IE 11 and see if it works as intended.

Comment: I think I see your problem with the offset. See my edited answer. You must use + offset + "px"; I believe it works such that you must have "px" with string values. By adding the offset it becomes a string somehow.

Comment: it still jumping when  i drag the scroll, i think is because as the left attr depends on the position of the scroll left, the scroll is much faster than the repaint of the element that ie can do to keep it at the offset left position

Comment: you have a slow machine?

Comment: i tried it on a another machine, and it happens the same thing, and searching the internet, giving a div a left attr than its changed by jquery could be a problem when repainting

Comment: Correction - I do see the flicker in IE 11.